# How to extract only numbers with awk

Tags: awk, numbers

Hello i have the following output:

```
replication complete (rid=969811 lid=969811)
```

or sometimes:

```
no change of listener transaction id for last 0 checks (rid=971489 lid=970863)
```

now i want to use awk to get only the numbers from rid and lid, the following works only with the first option

```
|awk -F'[^0-9]*' '{print $2-$3}'
```

Comment: Do you want to print (extract) the two numbers as your subject and text says or do you want to print the result of subtracting the second number from the first as you script would do? Please edit your question to show the EXACT expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ echo "no change of listener transaction id for last 0 checks (nid=971491 lid=970876)" |
awk -F'[()]' '{gsub(/[^0-9 ]/,"",$2); print $2}'
971491 970876

$ echo "no change of listener transaction id for last 0 checks (nid=971491 lid=970876)" |
awk -F'[()= ]' '{print $(NF-3), $(NF-1)}'
971491 970876

$ echo "no change of listener transaction id for last 0 checks (nid=971491 lid=970876)" |
awk -F'[()= ]' '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) m[$i]=$(i+1); print m["nid"], m["lid"]}'
971491 970876

$ echo "no change of listener transaction id for last 0 checks (nid=971491 lid=970876)" |
awk '{gsub(/.*\(|[^0-9 ]+|\).*$/,"")}1'
971491 970876
```

etc., etc.... The right one for you really depends what else you plan to do with the text.

Hmm, I now see in your question that you MIGHT want to print the subtraction of one number from the other instead of printing the numbers as I thought. Here's one way based on the above:

```
$ echo "no change of listener transaction id for last 0 checks (nid=971491 lid70876)" |
awk -F'[()= ]' '{print $(NF-3) - $(NF-1)}'
615
```

Alternatives left as an exercise!

Comment: This is one of those VERY common cases where it's trivial to produce the output you want from the input you posted, but much harder to NOT produce output that you DON'T WANT from other variations of text that might be in your input that you haven't told us about. So, just think about what it does and whether or not anything different than you've shown us so far in your text might be a problem.

Comment: Um, because it assumes there are always exactly two numbers in the input, which obviously isn't true?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `awk`, if your goal is to work with `rid` and `lid` values.

```
awk -F\(rid=\|lid=\) '{print $2-$3}' yourfile
```

(OR)

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="(rid=|lid=)"} {print $2-$3}' yourfile
```

Comment: hi, but this don't work for me. when i print $1 i geht this replication complete (nid=969811 and when i use $2 i get this: 969811)

Comment: @colttt, Updated answer.

Comment: It's working fine for me. I tried in `GNU Awk 4.1.1`. What is the `awk` version?

Comment: `GNU Awk 4.1.1` the same.. i try  `echo "no change of listener transaction id for last 0 checks (nid=971491 lid=970876)" |awk 'BEGIN{FS="(rid=|lid=)"} {print $2}'`

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, this works in `GNU-awk 4` only .... [Defining Fields by Content in GAWK](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Splitting-By-Content.html)

```
echo "no change of listener transaction id for last 0 checks (rid=971489 lid=970863)" | 
gawk -vFPAT='[0-9]+' '{print $(NF-1), $NF}'
```

you get,

```
971489 970863
```

```
echo "replication complete (rid=969811 lid=969811)" |
gawk -vFPAT='[0-9]+' '{print $(NF-1), $NF}'
```

you get,

```
969811 969811
```

Note: if, you want to do subtraction

```
echo "replication complete (rid=969811 lid=969811)" |
gawk -vFPAT='[0-9]+' '{print $(NF-1)-$NF}'
```

you get,

```
0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F'=' '{print int($2)-int($3)}'
```

Works because of the way awk parses strings.